# ebpf: verify LD_ABS and LD_IND instructions

Tags: instructions, bpf, ebpf

I was reading the [verifier](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L8522) code, in particular the part verifying safety of `LD_ABS` and `LD_IND` instructions (check_ld_abs()). As the comment says, these instructions implicitly expect input in `r6` register, i.e. this is where we have to load pointer to `__sk_buff`. So I verified that the following program of type `BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER` will be rejected by the verifier:

```
struct bpf_insn prog[] = {
    BPF_LD_ABS(BPF_B, offsetof(struct iphdr, protocol)),
    /* exit with value 0 */
    BPF_MOV64_IMM(BPF_REG_0, 0),
    BPF_EXIT_INSN(),
};
```

...

```
>> 0: (30) r0 = *(u8 *)skb[9]
R6 !read_ok
```

i.e. it needs to prepare `r6` before `LD_ABS`:

```
BPF_MOV64_REG(BPF_REG_6, BPF_REG_1)
```

However, the comment also says about *explicit input* (in this case the input can be any register)? Is it only used by `LD_IND`? What are the differences with implicit mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no implicit or explicit *mode*. Those instructions simply take several *arguments*, some of which are implicit, some of which are explicit.

- The context is implicit because, as you explain, it must be referenced in `r6`, which means that *it is not passed explicitly to the instruction* by the user: You don't see `r6` in `BPF_LD_ABS(BPF_B, offsetof(struct iphdr, protocol))`. It is an implicit convention that the instruction will expect the context from that register.
- By contrast, the source register and immediate value, also used by the instruction, are part of the instruction itself in the bytecode, making them *explicit* arguments.

The [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/filter.html#ebpf-opcode-encoding) confirms it somewhat:

> eBPF has two non-generic instructions: (BPF_ABS |  | BPF_LD) and
> (BPF_IND |  | BPF_LD) which are used to access packet data.
>
> They had to be carried over from classic to have strong performance of
> socket filters running in eBPF interpreter. These instructions can only
> be used when interpreter context is a pointer to `struct sk_buff` and
> have seven implicit operands. Register R6 is an implicit input that must
> contain pointer to sk_buff. Register R0 is an implicit output which contains
> the data fetched from the packet. Registers R1-R5 are scratch registers
> and must not be used to store the data across BPF_ABS | BPF_LD or
> BPF_IND | BPF_LD instructions.

As a reminder:

- `LD_ABS` loads data from an absolute address, starting from the beginning of the context (stored in `r6`) and adding the offset contained in the `imm` field. The data is stored into `r0` (implicit output). It does not use the `src` register.
- `LD_IND` performs an indirect load, it first offsets the context with the (variable) value from the `src` register, and then adds the (fixed) `imm` value as a second offset to reach the bytes to load into `r0`.

Comment: does the `LD_IND` instruction _implicitly_ expect the context in `r6`? I looked at few test cases in `testing/selftests/bpf/verifier/ld_ind.c` and `testing/selftests/bpf/verifier/ld_abs.c` and it seems that R6 is expected to have proper context. However, I don't quite understand why `LD_IND` basically does offset twice, one from _src_reg_ and then with _imm_ ?

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that `LD_IND` is needed for those cases where it is required to calculate the offset into `skb` rather then to provide a constant _imm_ value?

Comment: That's the idea. It was also used with TC/XDP programs initially, but [direct packet access](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=969bf05eb3cedd5a8d4b7c346a85c2ede87a6d6d) mostly supplanted it for these program types. I think it's still useful for programs attached to sockets.